# sound pool is not loading file correctly

Tags: android, soundpool, android-mediarecorder

My soundpool is not loading its file correctly from sdcard. I came to know about this from logcat. Here i am writing my logcat too.
It is recording my sound correctly and file is also saved in sdcard too. but soundpool is not starting/loading it.
 It is continuously displaying this error message in logcat.

```
 LOGCAT : 
   08-13 00:20:30.076: V/AudioTrack(1726): Underrun user: 0, server: 0, flags 0013
08-13 00:20:31.488: V/AudioTrack(1726): Underrun user: 0, server: 0, flags 0013
08-13 00:20:32.309: V/AudioTrack(1726): Underrun user: 0, server: 0, flags 0013
08-13 00:20:32.809: V/AudioTrack(1726): Underrun user: 0, server: 0, flags 0013


        package com.javacodegeeks.android.audiocapturetest;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;

        import android.media.AudioManager;
        import android.media.MediaPlayer;
        import android.media.MediaRecorder;
        import android.media.SoundPool;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.provider.MediaStore;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.ContentResolver;
        import android.content.ContentValues;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

           private MediaRecorder myRecorder;
           private MediaPlayer myPlayer;
           private File outputFile = null;
           private String outFile = null;
           private Button startBtn;
           private Button stopBtn;
           private Button playBtn;
           private Button stopPlayBtn;
           private Spinner sp;
           private TextView text;
           public SoundPool spl;
           public int explosion = 0;
           private Button playMod;
           private Uri newUri;
           private static final String TAG = "SoundRecordingActivity";
           String [] singers = {"Atif Aslam" , "Arijit Singh" , "Shreya Goshal"};

           public MainActivity() {
               outFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
               outFile += "/audiorecordtest.m4a";
           }
           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
              sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

              ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,singers);

                   adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                   sp.setAdapter(adp);
              // store it to sd card
             //outFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                //    getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecord.3gpp";

             File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
              try {
                  outputFile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".m4a", sampleDir);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "No Memory Card Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
                  return;
              }


              myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
              myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
              myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
              myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
              myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

              startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
              startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    start(v);
                }
              });

              stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
              stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    stop(v);
                }
              });

              playBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
              playBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        play(v);    
                }
              });

              stopPlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopPlay);
              stopPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    stopPlay(v);
                }
              });

              playMod = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
              playMod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                playModified(v);    
                }


              });
           }

           public void start(View view){
               try {
                  myRecorder.prepare();
                  myRecorder.start();
               } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                  // start:it is called before prepare()
                  // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat() 
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   // prepare() fails
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

               text.setText("Recording Point: Recording");
               startBtn.setEnabled(false);
               stopBtn.setEnabled(true);

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start recording...", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

           public void playModified(View v)
           {
                int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
              if(minBufferSize > 0)
              {
                  mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate,
                           AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                                    mAudioTrack.setPlaybackRate(22050);

                                    mAudioTrack.play();
              }
              else
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this , "Invalid Sample Rate" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }

              String sing = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
              if(explosion != 0 )
              {
                  if(sing == "Atif Aslam")
                      {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Atif Aslam", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        spl.play(explosion, 0.98F, 0.98F, 1, 0, 1.3F);
                      }
                  else if(sing == "Arijit Singh")
                      {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Arijit singh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        spl.play(explosion, 0.3F, 0.3F, 0, 0, 2.0F);
                      }
                  else if(sing == "Shreya Goshal")
                      {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Shreya", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        spl.play(explosion, 0.8F, 0.8F, 0, 0, 0.6F);

                      }
                  else 
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "No File Found A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      return;
                  }       
              }
              else 
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "No File Found B",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  return;
              }

           }
           protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
               ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
               long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + outputFile);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
               ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

               Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
               newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

               sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
               Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }


           public void stop(View view){
               try {
                  myRecorder.stop();
                  myRecorder.release();
                  myRecorder  = null;

                  stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
                  playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                  text.setText("Recording Point: Stop recording");

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop recording...",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  /////////////////////////////////////
                 // addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
                 ////////////////////////////////////// 
               } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    //  it is called before start()
                    e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    // no valid audio/video data has been received
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

           public void play(View view) {
               try{
                   myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                   myPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
                   myPlayer.prepare();
                   myPlayer.start();

                   playBtn.setEnabled(false);
                   stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(true);
                   text.setText("Recording Point: Playing");

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start play the recording...", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }

           public void stopPlay(View view) {
               try {
                   if (myPlayer != null) {
                       myPlayer.stop();
                       myPlayer.release();
                       myPlayer = null;
                       playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                       stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(false);

                       text.setText("Recording Point: Stop playing");

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop playing the recording...", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }



        }
```

Comment: i would suggest do not use soundpool to play recorded audio clip they have limitation it cannot play big file

Comment: can i change frequency of sound using media player..?

Comment: i think you want to change pitch? can you explain your aim please?

Comment: am working on d same concept like voice changer

Comment: yeah exactly m working on same thing u just said like voice changer..
i just let the user to choose a singer and let him to listen its recorded voice into the voice of that singer.

Answer (score 0):

as i told you do not go with soundpool go cause it doesnot support big file
so use other than soundpool like

```
mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate,
                    channelConfig, format, bufsize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            mAudioTrack.setPlaybackRate(sampleRate);

            mAudioTrack.play();
```

use above snippest which will give you direction  use audiotrack concept to play your recorded file

where setPlaybackRate() method set the playback rate in which you can add extra rate or you can substract that original rate then your pitch will change

as per standard pitch changing rate is always in between 0.5 to 2.0 where 1.0 is original pitch

so use above snippest where in above code if you want to increase the pitch then

```
mAudioTrack.setPlaybackRate(sampleRate+22050);//here am assuming recording sample rate is 44100
```

in this case i added 22050 means playback rate will be 1.5 so your recorded file will play with pitch rate 1.5 hope it will help you happy coding

Comment: what should be the default sampleRate??

Comment: and how to get buffersize?

Comment: I have updated the code again do have a look. 
@Android is everything for me

Comment: Default sample rate for recording which is standard one is 44100

for entire code you can google "how to play recorded file trhough media track you will get it"